# BufferedReader getting error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

unable to read response from server, getting " android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException " Error.

> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
>   InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));   String serverResponse =
>   in.readLine();

```
 W/System.err(1212):        android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException                                                
 W/System.err(1212):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)       
 W/System.err(1212):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)                             
 W/System.err(1212):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)                                     
 W/System.err(1212):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)                             
 W/System.err(1212):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)                        
 W/System.err(1212):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
```

Comment: use a `thread` or `asynctask`

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

According to android documents all the network handling code should not be placed in main thread. It will work for older versions not for newer versions. So use thread or async task.

Answer (score -1):

Move this code to the `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask` or `Thread` as you are getting data from the Internet and any calls made to the Internet need to be done in the background Thread not on the UI Thread or it will give error.